# Did the west build tool change on its own overnight?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, build, ninja, zephyr-rtos

I'm writing programs for nRF52 using nRF Connect and Zephyr. From last night to this morning I have noticed a change in the output of the build tool. Obviously i can not make a screenshot of what it used to look like, but [this](https://academy.nordicsemi.com/courses/nrf-connect-sdk-fundamentals/lessons/lesson-1-nrf-connect-sdk-introduction/topic/exercise-2-1/) Dev Academy article from Nordic Semi has a screenshot:
[image]

All the targets are listed in separate lines, one can see beautifully what's going on. This was the case last night before I went to sleep. I did not update anything, I didn't even turned off my PC, VS Code was left open, nobody has touched anything. Now the output looks like this:

[image]

Please note, this is not the same build, don't worry about the sizes. It's about the fact that now I have no idea that the 197 build items are, because they are all in one line. How did that suddenly change?

And my question is not what I can do now to see the different targets, I don't want to know what command line switch would do that. What I don't get is how it is possible that today it is different than it was last night?? Oh, and it's Linux, so no windows update overnight or anything like that. I don't have any automatic update.

Any ideas? (I actually would like the old output back)

Comment: Did you start from clean?  It's not regenerating stuff that is already built.

Comment: @stark, That would look totally different again. In that case it would say: "ninja: no work to do." What I'm talking about is when you either change the code or do a pristine build. When there's actual stuff to build. On my 2nd image you can see that it has done 197 things. But the 196th was on the same line too and so was 195th before, overwriting the same line every time. Well, nearly every time. You see that the 1st thing and the 3rd were kept for some reason.

Comment: Sounds like a terminal setting.  Your line ending has changed from CRLF to CR.

Comment: @stark, interesting idea. How would it effect only certain lines and certain other lines not? See after generated/version.h there's a different line ending? I'm just curious. Btw a minute ago it was back to normal again. Then I restarted VS Code to see if it stays normal, and of course it has not. At least it's not about something getting sneakily updated. It must be another one of these VS Code weirdnesses.